# Element scroll at the same time as I scroll another

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to make a HTML element (in this case an object) scroll at the same time I scroll another element (div). So far I have tried multiple ways but cannot seem to get the element I want to move automatically to do so.

Here are a couple of ways I am trying to do this;

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $("canvas").scroll(function () {
      $("FrameStyle").scrollTop($("canvas").scrollTop);
   });
});

function elementOnScroll() {
    var a = document.getElementById('canvas').scrollTop;
    document.getElementById('FrameStyle').scrollTop = a;
}
```

Neither of these have had any affect on the scroll bar that should be moving and i'm not sure why now.

HTML:

```
<asp:Literal ID="litWebsiteFrame" runat="server"></asp:Literal>
  <div id="canvas">
    <canvas id="DrawingCanvas">
      <p>
        Unfortunately, your browser is currently unsupported by our web application. We are sorry for the inconvenience. Please use one of the supported browsers listed below.
      </p>
      <p>
        Supported browsers: <a href="http://www.google.com/intl/en_uk/chrome/browser/">Chrome</a>,
        <a href="http://www.opera.com">Opera</a>, <a href="http://www.mozilla.com">Firefox</a>,
        <a href="http://www.apple.com/safari">Safari</a>, and <a href="http://www.konqueror.org">Konqueror</a>.
      </p>
    </canvas>
  </div>
```

The literal is just the following html code:

```
"<object data='" + qa.GetURL + "' id='FrameStyle'></object>"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the selector symbol. FrameStyle and canvas is `ID`. You need to use the script like below.

```
$("#FrameStyle").scrollTop($("#canvas").scrollTop);
```

Comment: Ive changed it but still no effect.

Comment: share your HTML part.

Comment: Updated my answer. check it now. I missed the "#" for canvas. I though you have used html canvas.

Comment: Hmm I did this from your previous answer still no luck.